# Styling array mapped objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
return arr.map((entry, index) =>
            <View style={ this.state.interests.includes(entry) ? styles.optionSelected : styles.option}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addToInt(entry)}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "#22305D", paddingVertical: 15, paddingHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 18 }} key={entry}>{`${entry}`}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
```

I currently have this code to traverse my array and display all the values, but I want a way to change the styling of an individual object when pressed. The way I have it now, onPress adds that unique value to the array interests (100% sure this works), but the conditional styling isn't working. Is there a different way of handling this? I am trying to avoid setting a state for option1, option2, etc.. Thanks!

Comment: The way I'd approach this is by moving all relevant code to a separate component and introducing some `state` there that'd keep track of whether it was clicked on not, rather than creating one `state` to keep track of all clicks.

Comment: I solved w/ pure components
`<View style={ this.state.interests.includes(entry) ? styles.optionSelected : styles.option}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({refresh: !this.state.refresh})
                    this.addToInt(entry)}
                    }>
                    <Text style={[{ paddingVertical: 15, paddingHorizontal: 25, fontSize: 18}, {color: this.state.interests.includes(entry) ? "white": "#22305D"}]} key={index}>{entry}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>`